# Automating JavaScript AMD bundling and minification in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I'm working on a new project where performance and optimisation is absolutely key. My client is entirely written in JavaScript: dependancies managed with RequireJS with an MVC style architecture in Backbone. I've been doing research to try and find the best practice of bundling and minifying my JS files (possibly 100+ per page) in a way that is as automated and painless as possible within Visual Studio.

Some of the more prominent tools I've noted are YUI Compressor, MS Ajax Minifier and Google Closure - these look great; but things quickly get messy when trying to get them to play nicely with RequireJS. I've also been looking at RequireJS Optimizer which looks great in practice, but it takes dependancies on Node or Rhino which I don't think I can do.

After scouring the internets I'm struggling to find a way to make this happen - when I think about it, I'm probably asking for a incredibly comprehensive, intelligent tool which might not exist. I could make it work with YUI Compressor but as far as I understand it's going to be very hands on to make it work with many JS files and keeping it maintained.

I admit that I am a little inexperienced in this area - am I just over complicating things?

**My question:** Is there a better way of modulating and managing JavaScript dependencies in development which makes bundling and minifying easy for production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodejs has [binaries for windows](http://nodejs.org/download/). There is a pletora of tools in node to achieve what you aim for. I havn't touched on visual studio since a distant past life, but it seems like firing an external build script is pretty doable. See [this link](http://braincrunch.tumblr.com/post/7960551966/visual-studio-tip-running-your-build-scripts-inside-vs)

Comment: I'm okay with the build script, but my project is likely to be accessed by a number of other devs and having them all install Nodejs in order to build the project is my least desirable situation. EDIT: Although if I can feasibly achieve this through nuget or something, it might work out.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken nodejs has no dependencies on windows. Someone okay with going through the pains of using VS will find installing nodejs very straightforward.

Comment: If you're optimizing for RequireJS Node is the way to go, I've found that it's faster than Rhino/Java and installs with minimal fuss. No matter what tool you use, you'll need to install something (YUICompressor and Google Closure need Java, for example) and the other build tools don't support RequireJS bundling.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer correct - using the prebuild Node binaries for Windows was indeed the way to go. I can just include it in my project and set up a build event to execute RequireJS Optimizer on build time. From there it's just a case of making sure to switch to the minimised scripts when in Release mode.

Comment: @Stevie: Would you mind telling me how you added the build event in visual studio and how you managed to do the switch to minified scripts in release mode? I'm trying to achieve the same thing myself and I can't figure it out.

Comment: First thing you need to do is include the node.exe somewhere in your project, along with all the r.js optimizer scripts you need. Then open your project's properties and go in to Build Events - and add "node r.js -o build.js" to your Post-build events. Once you have done this, it will automatically run that build command after a successful build. Then from there it's just a case of making sure you point to the correct scripts folder in release mode - I have my project hooked up through Team City, so on a deployment I just burn down the old scripts folder and replace it with the optimized one.

Answer (score 0):

lots of tools available in Visual Studio marketplace, my favourite is "Bundler & Minifier"

[Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier)

key feature

1. you can bundle single js or css file
2. you can minify single js or css file
3. you can bundle/minify all js or css file
4. automatic bundle/minify on every build.